# Copying user-defined types from one database to another

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-types

I am charged with creating an export from several tables in one database to a identically configured tables in another database, so first I have to create the identical configuration in the second database.

The problem is, when the first database was set up, they used what seems like hundreds of user defined types. I am not the greatest typist in the world and recreating these on the second database is going to a nightmare.

These user-defined types must be stored someplace, but I can't find them. I am thinking if I found the location where these types are stored, I could copy them to the second database and avoid trying to fat-finger though a couple hundred user-defined types.

Can anyone tell me where these types are stored, or of there is another way to solve my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the database in SQL Server Management Studio, choose `Tasks > Generate Scripts...`. Then check user defined data types and table types. Click `Next` etc up until `Finish`.

Once you have the script generated, execute it on the database you want to create the types in.

[image]